# What are the pros/cons of Ondura for roofing?

Tags: roof, roofing, product-review

I came across [Ondura](http://www.ondura.com/) in Lowes this morning and had never heard of it.  It looks pretty slick.  Does anyone have experience with it to share?  I found no matches when searching here and was sort of surprised, as it seems very DIY for re-roofing.

Comment: This stuff looks like a good option, I'll have to take a trip to Lowes and check it out.  My concern is durability, it might hold up to rain/snow/hail but can it handle a 200 lbs man jumping on it! *We'll find out!*

Comment: Product specific questions are generally off topic.  Old question but it's drawing a lot of recent attention.

Answer (score 6):

As a shingle replacement, the main attraction seems to be the distinctive appearance of the product.

Since they define lifetime as "as long as you own the structure", the warranty could be less than the standard 20 year of shingles ... something to think about.

Most of the other benefits that I've read about are marketing... if this product is being compared to a metal roof, it certainly has some more interesting points.

Some of the stuff they try to sell it on, isn't really that relevant... such as:

- Can be applied over a shingle roof ... so can new shingles.
- Only to 2 layers though ... if you have 3 layers up there already then the benefit of not stripping the roof disappears.
- Generally less expensive than high grade shingles ... fair enough, if you're considering high grade in the first place.
- Easy to install ... so are shingles really ... the hardest part of roofing is generally getting on, and staying on the roof.

I think for the residential market, especially if you will have to strip the roof anyway, that the real selling point has to be the appearance the product will give your roof... if you love the installed look (and I agree, it can look very sharp) then it's probably not a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

I bought a house with this installed. It was about ten years old and worn out. I live on the wet side of the mountains in Washington State, 9 blocks from the ocean. It rains here...a lot. The special vent caps weren't installed right and leaked. Ten tons of silicone didn't slow the water down, judging by the globs of it I found. There are two real problems with this system, I've found.

1. The coating wears out quickly. The roof needs sealing every 5 to 7 years, especially here in rainland, and
2. It cannot have another roof laid over it. You MUST remove it, no matter what roofing you decide to use.

Another Thing: there's no ridge cap, they recommend roll roofing, which can easily come off in the wind. And it won't won't hold up when walked on. The website cautions against it. I DO NOT recommend it, spoken from hands-on experience. It's easy to work with and goes on easily, but it is a quickie fix at best

Answer (score 3):

Don't use it---you will be sorry.  I put it on a big job. 
Ondura turned the big job into big mistake. 
The material disintegrates in about 10 years. When they say it is environmentally
friendly they mean it turns to compost right on your roof.

Answer (score 3):

Complete Junk, not worth the hassle. before the ten year period it starts to lose its color and deteriorates, the ridge line breaks up and disintgrates.
Ondura will not back you up even when they say life time warranty which is really untrue you have to paint the roof after about seven years, I found this out after installing the junk.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely a horrible product. We installed it a year ago and it is leaking, it has not held up well in cottage country. We talked to several roofers after the fact for help they all agree it is a horrible product. After a year we have had to have the roof stripped.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished installing Ondura on my Garage (2-story Barn Style) over the existing asphalt shingles. It was a breeze to install other that the fact that it is very fragile to work with. I suggest avoiding windy days and make sure you are accurate with your hammer because **you "will" put a hole in this stuff with very, very little effort**. I only hope it holds up because this is absolutely the last roof I am ever doing on my own.

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially heavy-duty corrugated painted tarpaper. I did one small roof with the stuff, and by the end of the process was quite certain **I'd never use it again.** If you want a corrugated roof, use metal; if you want a tar-based roof, either double-coverage roll roofing or normal asphalt shingles are a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff is great. Me being a woman, I was able to put it on by myself and even cut it with no problems. I have had it on my barn as roofing and siding after 17 years, it still looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I found that after a warm day the nails become loose and then when it rained the water dripped through the screw holes.

Answer (score 0):

I glued two pieces together on a 5ft x 7 ft(5 ft long) open porch frame. This stuff lasted just over one year before it collapsed to the ground.